# Is Postfix default configuration secure for out-going website mail?

Tags: security, postfix

I installed Postfix with ubuntu 9.10, apache2 and php5.  I have an e-commerce website that sends out emails using the postfix installed on the server.  Do I need to perform any special configuration on postfix to ensure out-going mail with sensitive information is secure?

I installed Postfix with the command

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

The PHP mail() function worked immediately afterwards, so I did not modify postfix's default configuration.  Do I need to do more for security?

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://serverfault.com/questions/139948/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-prevent-exploitation-of-my-postfix-server) with an answer providing other good hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always check the configuration of the MTA. Anyway, if you bind Postfix only to 127.0.0.1 with `inet_interfaces` parameter, you can be quite sure, but never rely on defaults.