# Postfix: Connection refused on incomming mails

Tags: postfix

I'm running a postfix server - for several weeks without problems, but now mails bounce. After one day, I got the following mail from gmail, when I tried to send a mail to my server:

```
[...]
Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     <the mailadress>@<myserver>

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

[...] 
[mx.<myserver>. (0): Connection refused]
```

The logs *mail.log*, *mail.err* and *mail.warn* are empty except of some strange errors of the form:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[22141]: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/virtual, line 12: ignoring unrecognized request
```

The virtual aliases is also the only thing I changed in the last time (but afterwards it was still working).

Any hints how I could troubleshoot this?

Note that sending a mail to a local user from a local user works.

Also there is a open port although "127.0.0.2" looks strange to me...

```
$ netstat -a|grep smtp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:smtp *:*                     LISTEN
```

My main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = <my servername>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = <myserver>, localhost
relayhost = <my external smtp>
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`inet_interfaces` parameter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces) is set to `loopback-only`. This is why local mail delivery is working.

Change this to `all` and it will be listening on all interfaces.

Comment: Uh... I think I added this, because because I don't want it to be an open relay... Of course it shouldn't be a spambot. See [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/109225/is-postfix-default-configuration-secure-for-out-going-website-mail) for example.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to accept mail from remote systems then you have to have the MTA listening on your ethernet interfaces, not just loopback. If it's an outbound-only system, then add a firewall rule to block port access from remote networks.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, your email server is listening to the loopback address only as it is shown by `netstat` output. You can try commenting out the following line in your config.

```
#inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

Don't forget to reload/restart your postfix process. It is a good idea to confirm this change was successful using `netstat`.